# String content become random integer after using append()

Tags: python, dataframe, append, data-cleaning

I'm writing a function to filter tweet data that contains search word.
Here's my code:

```
def twitter_filter(df, search):
  coun = 0
  date_ls = []
  id_ls = []
  content_ls = []
  lan_ls = []
  name_ls = []
  retweet_ls = []
  cleaned_tweet_ls = []

  for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if search in row.cleaned_tweet:
      date_ls.append(row.date)
      id_ls.append(row.id)
      content_ls.append(row.content)
      lan_ls.append(row.language)
      name_ls.append(row.name)
      retweet_ls.append(row.retweet)
      cleaned_tweet_ls.append(row.cleaned_tweet)
      
  new_dict = {
      "date": date_ls,
      "id": id_ls,
      "content": content_ls,
      "lan" : lan_ls,
      "name" : name_ls,
      "retweet" : retweet_ls,
      "cleaned_tweeet": cleaned_tweet_ls,

  }
  new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
  return new_df
```

Before filter:

```
cleandf['name']
Out[6]: 
0            PryZmRuleZZ
1         Arbitration111
2                4kjweed
3         THEREALCAMOJOE
5              DailyBSC_
     
130997     Rabbitdogebsc
130999          gmtowner
131000    topcryptostats
131001     vGhostvRiderv
131002          gmtowner
Name: name, Length: 98177, dtype: object
```

After filter, user's name becomes random integer:

```
cleanedogetweet['name']
Out[7]: 
0             3
1             5
2             9
3            12
4            34
 
80779    130997
80780    130999
80781    131000
80782    131001
80783    131002
Name: name, Length: 80784, dtype: int64
```

This problem only happened in user's name columns, other columns that contains string are ok.

I expected to remain the original user name, how can i solve the problem ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data in text format (not in image) so that error can be reproduced and then debugged?

Comment: Change `name_ls.append(row.name)` to `name_ls.append(row['name'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas dataframes, each row has an attribute called `name`.

You can use the `name` attribute to get the name of the row. By default, the name of the row is the index of the row.

So it's better that your column name would not be `name` because it will conflict with the `name` attribute of the row.

You can use the `rename` method to rename the column name and use another name like `username`, or you can change your function to this:

```
def twitter_filter(df, search):
coun = 0
date_ls = []
id_ls = []
content_ls = []
lan_ls = []
name_ls = []
retweet_ls = []
cleaned_tweet_ls = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if search in row.cleaned_tweet:
        date_ls.append(row['date'])
        id_ls.append(row['id'])
        content_ls.append(row['content'])
        lan_ls.append(row['language'])
        name_ls.append(row['name'])
        retweet_ls.append(row['retweet'])
        cleaned_tweet_ls.append(row['cleaned_tweet'])

new_dict = {
    "date": date_ls,
    "id": id_ls,
    "content": content_ls,
    "lan": lan_ls,
    "user_name": name_ls,
    "retweet": retweet_ls,
    "cleaned_tweeet": cleaned_tweet_ls,

}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dict)
return new_df
```